# How to PIVOT without aggregation in Presto

Tags: python, sql, presto

I have a table like this:

[image]

and want do a pivot without aggregation to get a result that looks like this:

[image]

This is straightforward in <strike>standard</strike> [T]SQL, but I need to do this in Presto which doesn't have a PIVOT function.  How does one do this with Presto functions?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/2448 already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
select t_us.display_name, t_us.site_count as us_cnt, t_for.site_count as for_cnt
from t t_us join
     t t_for
     on t_us.display_name = t_for.display_name and
        t_us.locationtype = 'US' and
        t_for.locationtype = 'FOR';
```

I would recommend conditional aggregation for this, but you specifically ask for another solution.

By the way, `PIVOT` is *bespoke* syntax.  It is not standard.  Both this solution and conditional aggregation are SQL standard solutions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Corrected strike-through text to reflect what I should have written originally.

Comment: Shouldn't `t_us.locationtype = 'FOR';` be `t_for.locationtype = 'FOR';` ?